# How to call javascript function from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want to execute javascript function from code behind page.

I have two way that first that I can call javascript of html page in my code behind.

second is that i can write javascript function in to my code behind.

but i am not which one is better and how can i do this.

Please tell me that how can i do this.

Comment: I really cannot understand what is your issue!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(...)
```

Look [here](http://arun-ts.blogspot.com/2007/09/scriptmanager-registerstartupscript.html) for details

Comment: Thanks! I had enabled partial rendering and not using ScriptManager caused everything to stop working.  Nearly drove me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your codebehind

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "scrptName", "javascript: alert('hi'); ", true);
```

You can replace alert('hi'); with your javascript function you want to call from code behind.

Comment: what is the meaning of GetType() and scrptName

Comment: RegisterStartupScript (type, key, script)

here GetType() returns type of the page. And scrptName is the key.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx

check this link for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can call Js functions as a script registered on the codebehind itself.

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("key","value")
```

key is the name you want to give the script eg. "PageClose"
value is the;

```
stringBuilder str = new StringBuilder()
str.Append("<script = language='javascript'>");
str.Append("window.close();");
str.Append("</script>")
```

here instead of using the window.close you coud append your js function as a string, ideally i put this string builder class and build the script in the constructor if i need it always in the page

Then use this in the event handler you want to execute the script

```
Page.RegisterStartUp("PageClose",str.ToString());
```

This would place the javascript before the closing  tag of the page thats rendered

```
Page.ClientScriptBlock("PageClose",str.ToString());
```

This would place the JS function after the opening  tag of the page thats rendered

Hope this helps

Comment: StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.Append("<script = language='javascript'>");
        str.Append("{");
        str.Append(" chooseStyle(" + colr + "," + wd + "); ");
        str.Append("function changeCSS()");
        str.Append("}");
        str.Append("</script>");

        Page.RegisterStartupScript("PageClose", str.ToString());

I am using this.
But its not working

Comment: I want to set the value colr and wd in chooseStyle on page load.

but right now its not working