# calling alert box from code behind java in jsf

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, alert

I have a requirement to update the properties file based upon the input provided by the user in the jsf page.  After updating the file, user session should be cleared and  alert box should say 'setting has been updated' and the page should navigate to the login page.

I don't know how to call a alert box from java code.  I found this to be possible in asp.net. I searched google, but didn't get any possible solution

How can I make this possible?

All possible solutions are welcome.  Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
@balusc thanks for your pointer.  I am using JSF RI 1.2 and Richfaces 3.3.2

Comment: As per your question history, you're using RichFaces. Are you open to RichFaces targeted answers? In future JSF related questions, you should mention the JSF impl/version and any JSF component libraries used.

Comment: I am open to Richfaces targeted answer and also others.

Comment: Ok, keep in mind that mixing various  "major" component libraries like RichFaces + IceFaces + PrimeFaces + OpenFaces + etc isn't always a good idea. The one might collide with the other. RichFaces *must* have this kind of functionality, but since I don't use it, I can't tell from top of head.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the pointer. I first started my search with Richfaces. Since I was unable to find it, I thought other libraries would be helpful.  Ok I will focus with Richfaces based solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by using 'oncomplete' attribute in a4j commandbutton.  'oncomplete' attribute is used to call javascript function after the server side process is completed.

After completing the server side process, I called a javascript function which called an alert box and using

```
document.location="../login.jsf";
```

I navigated to the login page.

Any suggestions regarding this solution is welcome.

Thanks every one for the answers and comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/) dialog.

PrimeFaces is an open source of components that enhance GUI and development.

The dialog has action listener on buttons, so when the user approves reading the dialog, you can redirect him to any page the you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will look into it and get back to you.

Comment: plz correct me, if I am wrong.  after completing the server side process, I need to show the dialog box and when the user approves it, I need to naviagate to the other page using javascript correct?

Comment: @mvg - not using javascript. use server side code to navigate:

Answer (score 1):

For displaying alert-box you can use below code in your bean :

```
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(facesContext, "alert('Setting has been updated');");
```

Clearing the session :

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
session.invalidate();
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this is IceFaces specific. You should mention as such.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Is JavascriptContext available only at IceFaces?

Comment: Sorry it was IceFaces specific, but <rich:modalPanel> used to show modal alert box might help you.

Comment: <rich:modalPanel> cannot be called from managed bean to my knowledge. Plz correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @mvg but I think it can be rendered via managed bean. Render it true when required & false on verification. This link might help you http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/modalPanel.jsf#

Comment: @Nayan Wadekar I expected the answer similar to the one you posted JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall.  Sad it is available only at IceFaces

Comment: @mvg In our project we have made custom popUp & not using Javascript anywhere. So I suggest you to build your own popUp using <rich:modalPanel> & control it in ManagedBean.

Comment: Anything similar available for non IceFaces users?  I'd like to do exactly this, but from "pure" JSF 2...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rich:modalPanel` with the `showWhenRendered` attribute set to a boolean property of your managed bean. Then just reRender the parent of the modal panel after your call.

[List of attributes for modal panel](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/rich/modalPanel.html)

Eg:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="modalParent">
   <rich:modalPanel showWhenRendered="#{bean.someBooleanValue}">

   </rich:modalPanel>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

And your button/link would have `reRender="modalParent"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will work with it and get back to you.

Comment: I tried showwhenrendered as suggested by you with no success.  If showwhenrendered is "true" value for this attribute makes a modal panel opened as default when the page loads. It doesn't open after the server side process completed. Plz correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You need to put the modalPanel inside another component and reRender the outer component.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/212127/JSF/java/invalidate-existing-session-create-new)

```
<%

ExternalContext ectx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)ectx.getResponse();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)ectx.getSession(false);
session.invalidate(); 
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('Setting has been updated');
location.replace('/index.jsp');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Is it possible to implement this  without the use of scriptlet?

Comment: What do you mean? If you wish to ALERT the user, you need to use javascript. If you just want to put a box on the page and redirect, you can just show html and use a meta tag. Perhaps a better solution is to redirect to the homepage and have the homepage detect the reason and show a message. Here is a discussion on redirect http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=530461

Comment: Sorry, if my question did not sound clear.  Clearing session is not a problem.  I want to know is there any possiblity in JSF similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679218/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind.  Sorry again if my question is not clear

Comment: @mplugjan: Scriptlet is not the same as Javascript. Scriptlets are those old fashioned `<% %>` things whose use is been discouraged since over a decade. Mvg just aksed if it was possible without them (and it is).

Comment: Ah, I see - never used the name scriplet before. I put the <% %> there to show where the javascript would go and where the java.