# Call javascript function from C# ASP.NET code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I want to call a javascript function from the code-behind file - but not after the user clicked something. The call will take place when a condition is true.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Edit:

I have now "fixed" it with querystring values, and putting ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered in Page_Load...but I wish there could be a neater way.

Comment: Why are you doing that?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The easiest way is to google on "Execute JavaScript function from ASP.NET codebehind"

Comment: I want make a temporary change on the .aspx page with javascript if a code-behind method returns a specific value. I have googled but not found what I am looking for. Only found event executed javascript calls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call javascript function from code behind?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679218/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)(now [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx)) or [Page.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (now [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx)). But, that depends on what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method seem to work when it's in Page_Load, but I want to fire it else where...

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to execute js code when something changes on the server, then you need to first think how you are going to monitor changes on the server from the client (js) code.

- Probably:

  - you will need to have javascript timer (`window.setTimeout(...)`) running on the client side,
  - which fetches the server side state using ajax call (`jQuery.get(...)` for example);
  - then you need to check if the state is what you are expecting and
  - then execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

neater way!

In .aspx near the bottom of the `</form>` tag:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"/>
```

In .cs

```
Literal1.Text = "<script>YourJSFunction();</script>";
```